# How can I be sure that I am using the real Facebook?

Tags: tls, certificates, digital-signature

I type `www.facebook.com` into my browser's address bar and press enter, then use Facebook.

Could I actually be visiting a fake Facebook even if I see a URL of `https://www.facebook.com` and a lock icon by the side of the address bar?

Comment: Hmmmmm... How can you be sure that you are using the real Security StackExchange and not something set up to deceive you by providing you false answers? Even if it is the real Security StackExchange, how can you be sure that the answers you get are good, and not upvoted by many meat-puppets? At the end of the day, you need to gradually build a trusted base of information yourself, and evaluate every piece of information (including all in this thread) critically, and then come to your own conclusions. Similarly, how can you be sure that there is no intentional backdoor in your browser???

Comment: Furthermore, Lenovo once installed a fake certificate that allows any attacker to decrypt all your HTTPS connections (http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/02/lenovo-pcs-ship-with-man-in-the-middle-adware-that-breaks-https-connections). Dell did the same stupidity a short while later (https://www.extremetech.com/computing/218437-dell-laptops-may-have-a-lenovo-superfish-size-security-problem).

Comment: You can also consider disabling all certificates that use 1024-bit keys or less or are not on the Mozilla Included CA Certificate list (https://mozillacaprogram.secure.force.com/CA/IncludedCACertificateReport), and also disable StartCom certificates (https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/07/07/google_ban_hammer_drops_on_wosign_startcom_in_two_months).

Comment: An interesting thought is raised by a colleague of mine who says that his home connection is advertised at 200mbps but his PC has only a 100mbps network card. When he uses fast.com he sees around 80mbps, when he uses speedtest.net he sees 200mbps. Makes me question if his ISP is giving him their own version of speedtest which always shows the advertised rate. I'm not naming the ISP because I've not witnessed it myself so I don't want to make any assumptions or claims to that effect. But I suppose in theory it's possible, and there's not really anything we can do about it

Comment: @user21820 hopefully the answers here would give include some justification, and not just a "yes" or "no".

Comment: Even if you are using the real Facebook, how can you be sure Facebook isn't just a phishing site for the *real* social network, Facebok?

Comment: Do the posts seem insipid and inane? If so, it's probably the real Facebook.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Of course; we evaluate reliability of everything, not on a binary scale. But the whole point is that we have to evaluate everything, and cannot just ask on Security SE expecting the answers to tell us facts. =)

Comment: I'd suggest to use the official Facebook app, but then you'll have two (or more) problems...

Comment: @darrenH: or maybe his isp is directly linked (or even, hosting) that particular site's website?

Comment: How can you be sure that you are using the real Facebook and not some shady side designed to collect your personal data and sell it to advertisers? Oh wait...

Answer (score 51):

You can confirm that you're on the real Facebook by a variety of ways:

1. Inspect the certificate used to secure the site. Open up your certificate (instructions vary by browser) and see what it says - is it issued to Facebook? Is it in a valid time period? Now, look at who signed that certificate, again, turn a critical eye towards it. Make sure everything makes sense. Go down the certificate chain until you get to the root certificate. Now, go to your favorite search engine and check that none of the certificate vendors have been in the news for a compromised private key. Unfortunately, the CA based ecosystem means you have to just trust the root CA, to some degree.
2. Check the IP address you're connecting to - use your favorite NSLookup tool to see where your DNS is pointing you when you connect to facebook.com. Take that address to google, see if it matches what people commonly say Facebook's public IP address is.
3. See if other people have recently reported issues connecting to Facebook over TLS, or have any concerns. Consider if those concerns seem valid to you, or if they seem like the user is just doing something incorrectly.

Next, take all the data you've gathered from the above points, and any other reconnaissance you've done. Think critically about whether you think it's reasonable that all of the above has been faked by a convincing virus, evil malicious actor on your network, or Mark Zuckerberg having a laugh. Also consider that the issue you want to avoid (submitting or viewing information from Fakebook rather than Facebook) and think if it's possible that the eventual consequences (data leak) could happen in another way, such as a screengrabber or keylogger virus running and just recording your input into the real Facebook. Then, consider if the risk outweights the value you'd gain from logging into Facebook. Then realize that Facebook gives you no value and decide it's not worth the risk.

Comment: "Also consider that the issue you want to avoid (submitting or viewing information from Fakebook rather than Facebook) and think if it's possible that the eventual consequences (data leak) could happen in another way, such as a screengrabber or keylogger virus running and just recording your input into the real Facebook."  Or even Facebook themselves recording the info you put into the real Facebook.

Comment: "Take that address to google" How do I know that the website I'm connected to is Google?

Comment: @JMac While it can't be taken as a fact, I'm wording my answer as though the user implicitly trusts Facebook with their information.

Comment: @Acccumulation You go to Google2, obviously. Seriously though... You use a device you trust to be uncompromised, preferably on a separate network. Unfortunately with the issue of Authentication, every question comes down to "Who do you choose to trust?" It's all very Solipsism-y.

Comment: Excuse my pedantry, but "Mark Zuckerburg having a laugh" would definitely still count as interacting with the real Fecebook, unless you meant the "berg"->"burg" typo as a different person.

Comment: @Adonalsium Oh I totally get that.  I'm just adding another layer to show that you basically can never escape the issue of trusting your software or hardware. (yay systems that are too complicated and interdependent for people to understand fully on their own!)

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar Conceivably MZ has the resources to tell someone to set up an entirely fake Facebook that is indistinguishable from the real Facebook, and redirect a specific inbound IP to that server instead. It's the fake Facebook, you could be talking with paid Facebook employees trying to deceive you, and you have no real way to tell that you've been routed to a different web server.

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar I cannot tell if "Fecebook" is an accidental or intentional typo (and, if intentional, I can't tell whether it's a example of the domain-squatting covered in these answers or if you harbor ill will toward Facebook). Either way, it's amusing since your comment is about a typo.

Comment: Facebook has a pretty short DNS TTL. Manually following the delegation chain for `www.facebook.com.` I end up with a CNAME to `star-mini.c10r.facebook.com.` which in turn has an address record with a TTL of only 60 seconds. While I do seem to consistently receive the same IP address when resolving that, this is something to watch out for.

Comment: @Adonalsium: Your comment about "Who do you trust?" should really be in your answer. Because your whole post relies on you trusting your browser not to give you fake information about the webpages you visit and the certificates you view.

Comment: Note that the browser isn't necessarily connecting to whatever nslookup does resolve www.facebook.com to.

Comment: @Acccumulation If you are the distrustful kind, you can always hand-deliver your packets in paper form to Google in California.  They might look at you odd, and they might have to go find some retired employees who remember what this dead tree material is and how to operate it without a touchscreen.

Comment: @Cort Ammon How do I find out Google's address?

Comment: @Acccumulation Use the internet for an initial address, and walk there.  If it looks like its a giant expensive Google plant site, you probably have found Google.  Along the way, maybe ask a few random people where the Google plant site is, to make sure they all give you the same answer.  If that is an insufficient level of confidence, then we probably need to have a much longer discussion of *precisely* what it means for an entity to be Google, because you're going to enter tin foil hat territory pretty quickly.  Make sure you know where you towel is =)

Comment: @Acccumulation Related, you might be interested in [Key Ceremonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_ceremony).  Generally speaking, I tend to call questions like "Did I find the right Google address" to be tin foil hat territory, but the people who do Key Ceremonies actually live in that territory, so it's not THAT crazy!

Answer (score 19):

This is exactly the problem that HTTPS is designed to solve. If you visit Facebook (or any other site for that matter) using a URL that starts with `https://` (*not* `http://`), then there are a number of security measures your browser will automatically employ to make sure that the site it connects you to really is the one displayed immediately after `https://` in the URL bar, and warn you if it's not.

Let's briefly go over these security measures so that you will have a better understanding of how they work and the conditions under which they are effective (or ineffective).

**How Domain Names Work**

When you first visit a URL like `https://www.facebook.com/` the first thing your browser will do is extract the site's domain name from the URL you provided. The domain name is the portion of the URL that comes after "https://" at the beginning of the URL, and *before* the next "/". In this case, the domain name is "www.facebook.com".

Within the domain name there are multiple labels separated by periods (`.`). The rightmost label, in this case, `com`, is the top-level domain. The label to the left of that, in this case `facebook`, is a subdomain of the top-level domain (`.com`), and any other labels to the left of *that*, such as `www`, are subdomains controlled by that domain's owner. So while a domain like `secure.facebook.com` is controlled by Facebook (since they own the `facebook.com` domain name), a different domain like `www.facebook.com.login.site` would be controlled by whoever owns the `login.site` domain (probably not Facebook).

This is important for you to understand, because while `https://www.facebook.com/` is the correct URL for Facebook, `https://other.site.com/www.facebook.com` is *not*, nor is `https://www.faceb0ok.com/`, `https://www.faceboook.com/`, or `https://www.facebook.com.secure.site/`. If the domain name you see in the URL bar does not end with exactly `facebook.com`, your browser will not know that you really mean to connect to Facebook, and therefore cannot protect you from connecting to a different site that's only pretending to be Facebook.

**Domain Name Verification**

Once your browser has the domain name of the site you visit, it will connect to that site using a process known as a TLS handshake. (Again, this is assuming you're visiting the site over https.) As part of this process, the server you connect to (whether the real server or a fake one) must present your browser with a special file known as a TLS certificate. This file must contain a signed statement from a third party known as a Certificate Authority which your browser already trusts. The statement will tell your browser what cryptographic key to use when contacting the website you requested, and your browser will ask the server you connected to (whether real or fake) to prove that it controls that key before it sends any further information to that server.

Because the TLS certificate has to be signed by a third party your browser already trusts, the server you're talking to cannot fake the information in that certificate. And because the certificate contains the real key of the server you're trying to contact (in our case, facebook.com), a fake server won't be able to convince your browser that it is legitimate and your browser will display a warning to you, telling you that the site you're connecting to might be fake.

For more on this process, see [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/29865).

**But is that enough?**

Can your browser be tricked into loading a page from a fake version of Facebook even if the URL bar says `https://www.facebook.com/`?

Under normal circumstances, no. Provided you check that you are using https and that the domain name is the right one, these built-in protections will usually be enough to ensure you really are talking to the real `facebook.com`.

There may be rare circumstances however where someone might be able to impersonate Facebook despite these protections. For example, if you install a custom trusted Certificate Authority on your computer, the owner of that Certificate Authority may be able to impersonate Facebook. At work, your employer may have done something like this already to your work computer, so use caution when browsing the web with a computer you do not own. (Same goes for computers at a school or library.) Malware on your computer might also be able to install its own certificate authority or bypass your browser's protections some other way.

There are also other, more uncommon ways an attacker might be able to trick your browser into connecting to a fake facebook.com, such as compromising a Certificate Authority trusted by your browser, but I won't go into those methods in detail, as they are very unlikely.

If you suspect that, despite these protections, your browser may be connecting to a fake facebook.com without warning you, you *might* be able to find out if that is the case using some of the methods explored in [Adonalsium's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/174729/29865), but even those methods are in no way foolproof.

But again, for most users, verifying that you are connecting over HTTPS and that the domain name displayed in the URL bar is correct should be enough for you to be reasonably sure you are indeed talking to the real Facebook.

Comment: Facebook uses preloaded HSTS. When I browse to `https://www.facebook.com`, among the response headers are `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload` Consequently, any modern browser (one that supports HSTS) won't just *warn* about SSL/TLS issues, but outright refuse to let you connect to Facebook at all.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling HSTS preload does not enforce a static public key. It only disables plain http, that's it. Fake facebook could be https, with a proper end-entity certificate, only a different root certificate.

Comment: @kubanczyk No, HSTS doesn't enforce a particular key (but HPKP could, to some extent, by effectively mandating the use of one of two specified CAs). However, my comment was in response mainly to "and warn you if it's not" in the first paragraph. When HSTS is in use, with a client that implements HSTS as defined, one of its effects is to turn any SSL/TLS warning into a fatal error. So if there is any problem which would cause a SSL warning in a non-HSTS situation, that same problem will prevent the user from browsing a known-HSTS site at all. With preloading, that includes the first visit.

Comment: A URL can have a username:password@ before the host name; some scammers used to use this to make http://facebookcom@scammers-r-us . com/ look like a Facebook URL

Comment: didn't domains have an implicit trailing `.` (www.facebook.com.), which is the actual top level domain for everything?

Comment: @BrianH. That's called the DNS root. It's not considered a top-level domain; it's actually one level above that. But yes, `www.facebook.com.` will indeed resolve to the same IP as `www.facebook.com`. Trailing dots are not commonly used on the web like that though, and most certificates won't include the FQDN in their list of covered domain names, so you'll get an error if you try to visit Facebook like that in most popular web browsers. It's not really something the average user needs to concern themselves with.

Comment: @Ajedi32 thanks for clarifying, I do believe that most of this answer is something the average user doesn't need to concern themselves with though :p

Comment: @BrianH. Maybe. I think the first paragraph and "How Domain Names Work" sections are pretty important for everyone to understand (in order to avoid phishing and entering sensitive data into insecure sites). The rest I agree is not crucial for everyone, but since the OP explicitly asked "how" I felt a bit more explanation was necessary than "just trust your browser; it knows what its doing". Hence the (very basic) explanation of how TLS works and under what conditions it is effective.

Answer (score 10):

The fact that the URL is `https://` (where `s` stands for security) and that the browser displays the lock *in the URL-bar* is the proof. This means that the HTTPS protocol is used, where the websites has to provide a certificate proving their identity. So as a user, you need to make sure that HTTPS is used and that you are on `facebook.com` and not something else (like `faceb00k.com`).

However, if your device has been hacked or is controlled by someone else (e.g. your employer) you can not be sure about this (or anything, for that matter).

Comment: May I suggest adding a bit about not installing untrusted certificates? And about domain names where some of the letters have been replaced with well-chosen Unicode look-alikes? While no decent CA would issue a certificate for a name that looked exactly like Facebook, it could be an issue with less famous domain names.

Comment: It is only the proof, that your connection is not intercepted, but not the proof you're using the real facebook. Everybody can get a certificate for domains which look like they may belong to facebook.You need look at the company name in the URL bar. Facebook has an EV certificate, which proofes it is the real facebook, while fakes can only have a DV certificate, which only proofes they are the owners of their (fake) domain.

Comment: Some malware may have installed its own root certificate, and used it to create  a perfectly valid EV Facebook certificate (things like this have happened, google superfish lenovo). Some malware may have infected your browser to pretend there's a verisign root cert when there isn't. At the end of the day, if your device has been hacked, nothing is proof of anything.

Comment: @allo, since when facebook uses EV certificate?

Comment: This answer is wrong, because with facebook you **cannot verify that you are really visiting facebook by looking at "https" and the lock icon alone**. https://imgur.com/a/uCorv

Comment: @Sumurai8 Could you elaborate what your picture is showing? I'm assuming *Veilig* is a translation of *Secure*. Is this an IDN homograph attack? Did you blank out something after `.com`?

Comment: The icon and https only show that you are visiting **a** site over https. It only tells you that there is a https connection between an endpoint and the site. I was getting at that the most important part is still checking if the domain name matches, because people are still more likely to mistype a domain name or autocomplete to a previous site, but I see that I misread part of your answer. Secondary issues are still dns poisoning (with a valid ssl connection to an other ip) and some government-type attacker signing their own certificate, which would require additional checks by the user.

Comment: @Sumurai8 There are lots of government-operated root CAs in the trust store. Of course, if a legitimate case can be made that, say, the Turkish government CA wrongly issued a certificate for `www.facebook.com`, then someone probably just burned a CA. It's all about risk vs reward tradeoff.

Comment: As @GuntramBlohm stated, there are reasons you can be totally hosed even if your device is brand new and not technically hacked. The Lenovo Superfish certificates were installed before even the point of purchase. Secondly, as Michael said, root CAs could be hacked, and that might be enough to fool your browser. If you have certificate pinning, you might avoid that second issue, but it will still fail if your corporation is controlling your certificate store.

Comment: Most comments here are technically true, but not relevant on the level the question was asked on.

Comment: @Crypt32 Sorry, I just assumed it because it would be unresponsible not to use EV certificates. But it seems they really do not use EV certificates.

Comment: I would like to tune in like others: the green lock and https: only mean that one of the CA implicitly accepted as authority by your browser gave a certificate to whatever entity you're contacting, to allow to call themselves Facebook.  *that's* what it means.  How honest that CA was in doing so, and how thorough was the identity verification, is left entirely open.  The only reason for you to be able to believe this, is that a CA that screws too many people, will end up not being trusted any more.

Comment: @entrop-x Yeah, sure, that is correct. But it's not relevant for how an ordinary user checks if they are on Facebook. No one, not even you, performs a evalutaion of the CA before updating their FB status.

Answer (score 5):

Just to complement the already very good answers, and to follow a bit on user21820's comment above, you build trust by parts and by analyzing.

I just wanted to point out that a basic point of your security setup in the situation you describe is the browser. Whoever wrote the code of the browser you are using has complete liberty of showing you that you are accessing www.facebook.com and displaying the green certificate while connecting you with whatever site they want. You would detect this situation by sniffing the ip traffic from your computer, but not by looking at the browser.

In the end, we all use a setup where we are trusting different persons/companies/institutions: whoever wrote the operating system, whoever installed it, whoever wrote the bios and other firmware in your hardware, whoever wrote the browser, the certificates installed in your system, etc. Most common setups are well-known so that they are more or less trustable, but more than anything we put our trust in numbers: if Microsoft or Google or a computer manufacturer had their software directing to dubious sites or stealing sensitive information, or if Mozilla installs an unsafe certificate, someone among the millions of users would likely notice one way or the other. It doesn't make it impossible for shady things to happen in your system or mine: just unlikely.

Comment: You are absolutely right that one needs to put trust in many things, and one cannot possibly check everything for one-self.  However, it is easier to put trust in something that is open, because it means that anyone could *potentially* check it, so the entity putting in back doors has potentially to expose one-self.  Of course, the real pain point in this is hardware, but you may hope that hardware is sufficiently low level not to be able to interfere with sophisticated stuff you do on higher, open layers.

Answer (score 0):

The original question can have two aspects.  One is "is my data ending up on the real facebook ?".  In other words, am I on the site of an imposter ?  The other one is: "could there be a MITM attack that is snooping on my connection ?".

In both cases, when the "green lock" appears in the browser, and we assume that the browser is not compromised, and has the right CA certificates, the answer to the question is equivalent to: "could any one of the trusted CA have produced another certificate with the domain name "facebook.com".  Now that's a hard question to answer, because in order to be able to verify this, one should in principle need to be able to see ALL certificates issued by ALL trusted CA, which is impossible, as they are not written down in any form of block chain or the like.  The token block chain was exactly invented to solve the problem of "proving no double spending" which is akin to the problem of proving "no double certificate".

An argument in favour of CA not doing such would be that a CA's business depends on being trusted, and hence on users not ever finding out that they were tricked by a rogue certificate issued by said CA.  If several facebook users would complain that they ended up on fakebook, that would be the end of that CA's business.    This is a valid argument to have some trust that CA don't sign certificates to fakebook.  However, it is not an argument against CA signing certificates for MITM snoopers (say, state-sponsored snoopers).  There is no way to find out if the MITM is just snooping.

With a MITM snooper, at the end of the day, you are really connected to the real facebook of course, but you have no way of knowing whether you're been snooped doing so.  I don't know what aspect the original question was emphasising: ending up at facebook but being snooped, or ending up on fakebook.  The "CA reputation" only matters for the second aspect.

Answer (score -1):

HTTPS is fairly good but if you are in China you'd hope they have not altered the SSL root CA cert authority such that you get a different result. I guess you could compare that with Google's 8.8.8.8 public DNS results?

http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-banishes-chinas-main-digital-certificate-authority-cnnic/

Comment: This does not add to what the other answers provide. Other answers say the same thing without specifically mentioning "China" (which is unnecessary because other countries as well as ISPs and organisations do the same thing)

Comment: I think China is the first country to have a root CA removed by a browser maker though? First I'd heard.

Answer (score -3):

There have been already many excellent answers.  I would like to tune in from yet another viewpoint.  When taken to the extreme, this becomes philosophical, and you have to draw the line *somewhere*:

- Does "Facebook" as I think I know it, even exist for real ?
- If it exists, what on earth could it be ?
- How many different Facebooks might exist ?
- Is there a real person by the name of Zuckerberg ? Is he really the boss of Facebook ? Does he have a twin brother ?

One can end up in total solipsism that way, if one puts every piece of received information (by your brain) in doubt.  At a certain point, you will have to accept a "hypothesis of reality".  That is the anchor of trust for the rest of the authentication information.  Maybe you know Mark Zuckerberg in person: you could ask him the true public keys in the certificates of Facebook. But maybe you only know about a thing called "Facebook because other people talked you about it.  In that case, how do you know you are on the *same* Facebook as what they were talking about it ?

So in the end, you might say that you don't care about the *absolute nature* of Facebook: what matters, is that the "Facebook" you're dealing with, is the same one you were *initially* dealing with upon first learning about it.  If there is, in reality, a genuine second (and even a third, fourth...) "Facebook" out there, but one of them is the one your friends showed you for the first time to make an account, and you can contact them, the only thing you want, is that you are later in contact with *the same Facebook* as initially.  So if you get a public key from one of your friends, that is the public key of the Facebook your friends are using, that's in principle good enough.  If your friends were, all of them, systematically, the constant victim of a MITM attack, well, it doesn't matter: that MITM *is* your Facebook: an entity on the internet.  Nobody said that that Facebook was a nice entity...

So, for entities on the internet, what matters often is *relative* authentication: the proof that you are contacting in successive sessions, the *same entity* than you contacted the first time.  You may realize that apart from the coherence of entity over different contacts, you don't know much about the entity you're contacting.

It can be different if you need the entity to be also a *legal* moral person that you might like to sue if ever it behaved badly towards you.  You should then, strictly speaking, obtain a certificate from the legal instance that has the power of jurisdiction over the entity you'd like to contact, the moral person behind "Facebook".  This can be the case if you contact a business partner on the internet, which you don't know apart from the fact that he's on the internet, say, a store on the other side of the world.

Finally, there's a third possibility, and Facebook most probably falls into this category.  You want to contact the entity "everybody knows and is well-known".  The different channels by which an entity is "well-known" should then also be used to spread the public key of that entity: printed journals, television, different web sites, etc...  If the same public key is distributed systematically and coherently by several other entities you also know somehow, you have a strong web-of-trust that signals that you can trust that public key to be the right one of Facebook.  This is something that doesn't really work well for relatively unknown entities, because its "web of trust" needs to spread wide enough that it touches different actors *you* already know and trust which only works for well-known entities.  I'm living in Europe, and I'd have a hard time obtaining a web of trust around me that could convince someone in Sidney to be absolutely sure he's dealing with me.

So we have 3 different categories of authentication of entities on the internet, depending on the use case:

- relative authentication: I don't know who you are, but you're the same entity that I contacted earlier
- legal authentication: I can only trust the legal issuer of identities
- web-of-trust authentication: "everybody" knows who it is through different channels, so this is the way to obtain the correct public key: the one everybody is using consistently.

A real-world use case may need the 3 aspects: I want to connect to the "well-known" Facebook "everybody knows" (even if there's a bar somewhere in Kazakhstan called "facebook", that's not the one I want to contact) ; I want to contact the *same* Facebook upon successive logins (even if there has been a selling of the brand name to another entity, say).  And if ever Facebook behaves badly, I want it to be a moral person that I could, eventually, sue in court.

As such, the trust we seem to put in CA is somewhat overdrawn, because we blindly trust entities (CA) to have verified this without checking ourselves, and independently of our use case.  After all, maybe the bar in Kazakhstan also has a certificate for "Facebook.net".  But it is easier and better than nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! This is a well-written philosphical answer, but I'm afraid it's not the kind of answer we are looking for here. This site is aimed at practical answers ("There is a lock icon that shows you're using SSL/TLS, and the title bar should show  the site name in green..."). That said, we _also_ have a Q&A site about [Philosophy.SE], that you may find interesting.

Comment: @Barth: I see what you mean, but my aim *was* to indicate a genuine difficulty of security with CA.  For instance, if you're working in a big company, and you're behind a firewall, the original question *how can I be sure that I'm on the real Facebook ?* might make sense, if your company has extra root certificates installed in your browser and is snooping on its employees, doing a systematic MITM attack on outgoing facebook traffic.  Your ISP is maybe also linked to a CA, and might do the same.  How would you find out ?

Comment: Of course it answers the question.  I'm not criticising anyone, apart from the comment of Barth who claimed that it wasn't an answer, and that the "right" answer should simply be based upon CA.  I'm explaining that the real answer to the question comes down to finding out whether the public key one has is genuinely corresponding to the entity one has in mind, and that this could mean 3 different things: "same as previous", "legal entity" or "same as what other people agreed upon".  "green lock" is based upon "whatever any single one of a set of given entities (CA in browser) tell me it is".